# Python creating a generator that outputs multiple items

Tags: python, list, generator

Is there a way in Python to generate multiple outputs at the same time. In particular I want something like:

```
my_gen =(i for i in range(10))
```

and say I have a parameter `batch_size = 3`. I would want my generator to output:

```
my_gen.next()
0,1,2
my_gen.next()
3,4,5
my_gen.next()
6,7,8
my_gen.next()
9,10
```

where on the last command, it only yields two numbers because there are only two numbers left even though the `batch_size` is 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the [`itertools` page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) there is a grouper function provided:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

And with that you can make your generator and wrap it with a grouper:

```
for my_tuple in grouper(my_gen, 3):
    print([x for x in my_tuple if x is not None])
```

Comment: Check the variable names in your comprehension

Answer (score 2):

IMO, no need for any libraries. You may just define your own batch generator

```
def batch_iter(batch_size, iter_):
    yield [next(iter_) for _ in range(batch_size)]
```

and just

```
next(batch_iter(batch_size, x))
```

A iteration-safe version would be

```
def batch_iter(batch_size, iter_):
    r = []
    for _ in range(b):
        val = next(iter_, None)
        if val is not None: r.append(val)
    yield r
```

Of course you may `yield tuple(r)` instead of just `r` if you need tuple values. You may also add an `else` clause and `break` the loop since once `val` is `None`, there are no more values to iterate

Comment: This doesn't work correctly when you use `next` the final time. Instead of yielding `[9,10]`, it raises an error.

Comment: @piccolo I just assumed you could expand from that idea. But I'll explicitly write a iter-safe func ;}

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension with the generator:

```
batch_size, max_size = 3, 10
my_gen = ([x for x in range(i, i + batch_size) if x <= max_size] for i in range(0, max_size, batch_size))
for x in my_gen:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the iterator/generator to have a multiple of the batch size elements you can simply do:

```py
gen = iter(range(12))
for x, y, z in iter(lambda: [next(gen) for _ in range(3)], 1):
    print(x, y, z)
```

If not; this should suit your needs:

```py
gen = iter(range(11))
for t in iter(lambda: [next(gen, None) for _ in range(3)], [None]*3):
    print(*[x for x in t if x is not None])
```

Pros:

1. iteration safe
2. readable
3. requires no library
4. short